# Create Yup nested object schema dynamically

Tags: javascript, formik, yup

For this "flat" object validation

```
const fields = [
  {label: 'Name', name: 'name', validation: yup.string().required()},
  {label: 'City', name: 'city', validation: yup.string().required()},
  {label: 'Phone', name: 'phone'},
]
```

I created `createYupSchema` function to get Yup schema object from `fields`.

```
const createYupSchema = (fields ) => {
  const schema = fields.reduce((schema, field) => {
      return field.validation 
      ? {...schema, [field.name]: field.validation} 
      : schema
  }, {})

  return yup.object().shape(schema)
}
```

The output is Yup object:

```
yup.object().shape({
  name: yup.string().required(),
  city: yup.string().required(),
})
```

But I would to have the possibility to use also nested object in `fields`

```
const fields = [
  {label: 'Name', name: 'name', validation: yup.string().required()},
  {label: 'Address', name: 'address.city', validation: yup.string().required()},
  {label: 'Phone', name: 'phone'},
]
```

So the Yup object should be:

```
yup.object().shape({
  name: yup.string().required(),
  address: yup.object().shape({
      city: yup.string().required()
  }),
})
```

Is it possibile to create this type of Yup object from `fields`?

Answer (score 5):

I resolved my question. Now `createYupSchema` works in this way

```
const createYupSchema = fields => {
  const schema = fields.reduce((schema, field) => {
    const isObject = field.name.indexOf(".") >= 0;

    if (!field.validation) {
      return schema;
    }

    if (!isObject) {
      return { ...schema, [field.name]: field.validation };
    }

    const reversePath = field.name.split(".").reverse();
    const currNestedObject = reversePath.slice(1).reduce((yupObj, path) => {
        return { [path]: yup.object().shape(yupObj) };
    }, {[reversePath [0]]: field.validation});

    return { ...schema, ...currNestedObject };
  }, {});

  return yup.object().shape(schema);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I resolved my question, using the "lazy" method:

```
const validateSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    items: Yup.array().of(
        Yup.lazy((item) => {
            return Yup.object({
                itemName: Yup.string().test(
                    'validate',
                    'warning',
                    (value) => {
                        if (value && item.itemDescription) return true
                        if (!value && !item.itemDescription) return true
                        return false
                    }
                ),
                itemDescription: Yup.string().test(
                    'validate',
                    'warning',
                    (value) => {
                        if (value && item.itemName) return true
                        if (!value && !item.itemName) return true
                        return false
                    }
                ),
            })
        })
    ),
})
```

Comment: Please next time explain the code you're giving, giving pieces of code or fixing the OP's isn't helping him or making him learn what the mistake is and how to fix it

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).